# Is every surface locally symmetric?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lattices-in-lie-groups

Can every compact connected 2 manifold be expressed as 
$$
\Gamma\backslash G/H
$$
where $ G $ is a Lie group, $H $ a subgroup of $ G $, $G/H $ a symmetric space, and $ \Gamma $ a discrete subgroup of $ G $? 
I know this is true for the orientable case. In fact the manifold $ G/H $ is holomorphic as is the covering map with fiber $ \Gamma $. I know that 
$$
RP^2 \cong O(3)/O(2)\times O(1)
$$ 
so it is in fact homogeneous. But what about the Klein bottle (connected sun of two projective planes)? Or even the connected sum of $ n $ projective planes? Are those surfaces  locally symmetric?

In your answer please provide an example of a triple $ (\Gamma, G,H) $. Preferably with G simple

Comment: Maybe I am missing something - but isn't every constant curvature space (of any dimension) locally symmetric?  The universal cover is symmetric, so doesn't that give you the result you want?

Comment: You do not even need compactness for this to hold.

Comment: I suspect you are thinking of surfaces up to diffeomorphism. To me, being a (locally) symmetric space is a property of *Riemannian* manifolds, so I am assuming you're asking if these surfaces admit Riemannian metrics which make them locally symmetric spaces.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin yes that’s what I’m thinking

Comment: @Jason Devito I'd love you to flesh out that answer more it sounds cool! And I’ve edited my question to emphasize that I want answers with nice matrix groups $  (\Gamma, G,H) $ provided