# Constant curvature equivalent to locally symmetric

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Is it true that a constant curvature metric on a manifold $M$ is equivalent to a presentation of $M$ as a locally symmetric space
$ M \cong \Gamma \backslash G/H $
where $G/H$ is a symmetric space and $ \Gamma $ a discrete subgroup of $G$?

I believe this is true based on the response of Jason DeVito to my question:

[Is every surface locally symmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567448/is-every-surface-locally-symmetric)

And for a topological manifold M homeomorphic to a locally symmetric space is there any sense in which the triple $ (\Gamma, G, H) $ is unique? Or can the triple be picked to be minimal in some way? For example pick H connected and G simple or semisimple or simply connected or of minimal dimension etc...

Comment: If $M$ is complete (and by constant curvature you mean constant *sectional* curvature), this is certainly the case, since all space forms are quotients of spheres or Euclidean/Hyperbolic spaces.

Comment: In dimension $>2$ there are lots of (locally) symmetric spaces that are not of constant curvature, so you'd best stick to surfaces.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin so is it the case that Jason DeVito is wrong in claiming "Maybe I am missing something - but isn't every constant curvature space (of any dimension) locally symmetric? The universal cover is symmetric, so doesn't that give you the result you want?" in a comment on my question linked to above? Also I would love it if you could give an example of a manifold of dimension $ >2 $  that admits a constant curvature metric but is not locally symmetric!

Comment: You didn't read my comment carefully. I'm addressing the converse statement. Your question said "equivalent" — these are only *equivalent* statements in dimension $2$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I see, so what is an example of a manifold that can be realized as a locally symmetric space but does not admit a constant curvature metric? And is there any algebraic characterization of such spaces among all locally symmetric spaces?

Comment: The simplest example is a Grassmannian (that is not a projective space). Look up *space forms* — as was already discussed, the simply connected spaces of constant curvature are very few.