# Is it possible to realize the Klein bottle as a linear group orbit?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, geometric-topology, algebraic-groups, homogeneous-spaces

Does there exists a Lie group $ G $, a finite dimensional representation $ \pi: G \to GL(V) $, and a vector $ v \in V $ such that the orbit
$$
\mathcal{O}_v=\{ \pi(g)v: g\in G  \} 
$$
is diffeomorphic to the Klein bottle?

The Klein bottle, $ K $, is homogeneous for the special Euclidean group of the plane
$$
SE_2= \left \{ \
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & x \\
-b & a & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : a^2+b^2=1 \right \} 
$$
Because there is a one parameter group $ H $ of translations up each vertical line
$$
H= \left \{ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : y \in \mathbb{R} \right \} 
$$
There is also an element that shifts horizontally by one unit
$$
b:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If we mod out $ SE_2 $ by the group generated by $ \langle H,b \rangle \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z} $ we just get a torus. Now if we include the rotation by 180 degrees
$$
r:=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then mod out $ SE_2 $ by the group generated by $ \langle H,r,b \rangle $ we get the Klein bottle $ K $. Since $ \mathbb{Z}=\pi_1(SE_2) $ and $ \pi_0(<H,r,b>) =<r,b> \cong \{ \pm 1 \} \rtimes \mathbb{Z} $  then we must have
$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \pi(K) \to  \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \{ \pm 1 \}  \to 0
$$
So we can conclude that $ \pi_1(K) \cong \mathbb{Z} \rtimes (\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \{ \pm 1 \}) $. It turns out that this particular semidirect product is isomorphic to the simpler semidirect product $ \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z} $ with presentation $ <a,b:abab^{-1}> $ . Thus $ \pi_1(K) \cong \mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z} $ (this fact can be verified using the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem and the fact that a Klein bottle is a connected sum of two projective planes)

As Steve D pointed out below, since the klein bottle has orientable double cover the torus then by applying LES of homotopy to the $C_2$ principal bundle we have
$$
1 \to \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \pi_1(KB) \to C_2 \to 1
$$
So the fundamental group is virtually abelian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.

A compact linear group orbit must have a transitive action by a compact Lie group (which is equivalent to being a compact manifold which admits a metric with respect to which it is Riemannian homogeneous) see

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409511/compact-linear-group-orbit-equivalent-to-linear-compact-group-orbit

The klein bottle is compact and aspherical (universal cover is the plane). The only compact aspherical linear group orbit is the torus see

[Riemannian homogeneous aspherical iff flat torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4382864/riemannian-homogeneous-aspherical-iff-flat-torus?noredirect=1#comment9166212_4382864)

Comment: Of course the Klein bottle group is virtually abelian, the Klein bottle is 2-covered by a torus. In your last presentation, this is the subgroup $\langle a,b^2\rangle$.

Comment: Usually an answer isn't copied back into the question -- it's fine keeping your answer right here where it is.  Also, I think I'm missing something: did you want to find an orbit that was diffeomorphic to the Klein bottle? You have a quotient of the group that's a Klein bottle, but is the idea that $\langle H,r,b\rangle$ is the stabilizer subgroup of some vector of some vector space?

Comment: You have probably already notice this, but if we let $V$ denote the real Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, then the set $K=\{\sin^2(ax+by+c)|\,\,a,b,c\in\mathbb{R},\,\,a^2+b^2=1\}\subset V$ is naturally identified with the Klein bottle.  The linear action of $SE_2$ on $V$ (induced from the action on $\mathbb{R}^2)$, is transitive on $K$.

Comment: Yes indeed!  $ C=\{ ax+by+c: a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, a^2+b^2=1 \} $ is the cylinder and carries a transitive action of $ SE_2 $ induced from the action on $ \mathbb{R}^2 $. Then $ T^2=\{ \sin(ax+by+c): a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, a^2+b^2=1 \} $ is a torus, $ c \sim c+2 \pi $ yield same function, again with the induced $ SE_2 $ action transitive. And finally, as you say, $ K=\{ \sin^2(ax+by+c): a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, a^2+b^2=1 \} $ is a Klein bottle, $ (a,b,c) \sim (-a,-b,-c) $ yield same function, with the induced action by $ SE_2 $ transitive.

Comment: So perhaps you should edit your question and answer to make $V$ finite dimensional.  Otherwise technically this is a solution.

Comment: oh haha sure that's actually a great point

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira Hi, I know this is old, but this post is highly relevant to my senior project. I'm wondering why the T^2=\{ \sin(ax+by+c): a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}, a^2+b^2=1 \} you defined in the above comment is a torus and not a klein bottle? As $(a, b, c) ~ (-a, -b, c + \pi)? I'm just not seeing how squaring the sine function does anything topologically.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extended comment on the question - apologies for posting as answer.

Firstly I find it really interesting that you have this transitive $SE_2$ action on the Klein bottle.  Naively one might think that as the Klein bottle inherits a locally Euclidean metric as a quotient of the plane by a subgroup $G\subset E_2$ (with $G\cong \pi_1(K)$), there would be such a transitive $SE_2$ action of isometries.  However $G$ is not central in $E_2$ so the action of $SE_2$ as isometries is not well defined.  Further if we consider pairs of geodesics parallel to the sides of a fundamental rectangle, meeting orthogonally at different points:
[image]

we see that the length of the vertical geodesic is doubled when the point does not lie in the middle vertical line.

This does not prove that $SE_2$ does not act transitively isometrically on the Klein bottle - but it is very unlikely as the points in the middle (and sides) seem to be genuinely different to the rest.

On the other hand, both here and in your [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414402/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-moebius-strip-as-a-linear-group-orbit#comment1062665_414402) you give beautiful transitive actions of $SE_2$ on the Klein bottle - which made me wonder what quadratic structure on the tangent bundle they might preserve.

Following the construction from your comment, parametrise the Klein bottle by $$K=\{(c,\theta)| c\in [0,1], \theta\in [0,\pi]\}/\sim,$$ with $k_1\sim k_2$ precisely when they result in the same set of lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$:$$\{(x,y\}|\,\,(\cos\theta) x+(\sin\theta) y\equiv c\mod 1\}.$$

As you said, the action of $SE_2$ on these sets of lines (induced from the natural action on $\mathbb{R}^2$), gives us an action on $K$.  A bilinear form on the tangent bundle is invariant under $SE_2$ precisely when it is induced by translations, from a bilinear map at a point, invariant under the stabiliser of the point.

The stabiliser of $(0,\pi)\in K$ is precisely translations by $(0,\lambda),\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$, translations by $(n,0),\, n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and rotations by $\pi$.  This is precisely your $\langle H,r,b\rangle$, so the two constructions you gave are the same (sorry - this is probably obvious to you, but I only just realised).

The action of $(0,\lambda)$ sends $(c,\theta)\mapsto (c+\lambda \cos\theta)$, so has derivative $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&\lambda\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$

The forms invariant under this are precisely the ones of the form: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&a\\-a&b\end{array}\right).$$

So your action is not compatible with any metric.  Locally though we can define an area form: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\-1&0\end{array}\right).$$

However the derivative of rotation by $\pi$ is: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right),$$ so area gets flipped when you cross the boundary that reverses orientation (as one would expect).

The only bilinear form that is globally invariant under $SE_2$ is then (up to scalar): $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&1\end{array}\right).$$

We do not need to worry about translations by $(n,0)$ as these have derivative the identity.

Apologies for rambling, but I found this action you described (two different ways) very interesting.