# Connected sum of two copies of $ RP^3 $

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Consider the space of planes in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. This space is known as the Grassmannian of affine planes in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. It is a line bundle over $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $
$$
\mathbb{R} \to \text{Graff}_2(\mathbb{R}^3) \to \mathbb{R}P^2
$$
where the map $ \text{Graff}_2(\mathbb{R}^3) \to \mathbb{R}P^2 $ associates an affine plane to the unique line through the origin that is orthogonal to it (equivalently the unique plane through the origin which is parallel to it).

In general the affine Grassmannian $ \text{Graff} $ is a vector bundle over the (regular/linear) Grassmannian $ \text{Gr} $
$$
\mathbb{R}^k \to \text{Graff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \text{Gr}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
where $ \text{Graff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is the manifold of all
$ n-k $ dimensional affine subspaces of $ \mathbb{R}^n $. And the map $ \text{Graff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \text{Gr}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is given by sending an affine $ n-k $ dimensional subspace to the unique $ n-k $ dimensional linear subspace which is parallel to it. It turns out that $ \text{Graff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ is diffeomorphic to the total space of the tautological bundle over $ \text{Gr}_k(\mathbb{R}^n) $ see [Affine Grassmannian and the tautological bundle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4367169/affine-grassmannian-and-the-tautological-bundle)

A familiar example of this is $ \text{Graff}_1(\mathbb{R}^2) $
$$
\mathbb{R} \to \text{Graff}_1(\mathbb{R}^2) \to \mathbb{R}P^1
$$
which is just the Moebius strip viewed as the manifold of all lines in the plane (these are affine lines so they don't need to go through the origin). An interesting structure here is that the Euclidean group  $ E_n $ acts by isometries and so takes any affine $ n-k $ dimensional subspace to another affine $ n-k $ dimensional subspace. Indeed $ \text{Graff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ has a transitive action by $ E_n $ and can be written
$$
\text{Graff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cong E_n/(E_{n-k}\times O_k)
$$
where $ E_{n-k} $ is the part of the stabilizer of a fixed $ n-k $ dimensional affine subspace consisting of isometries of the subspace itself while $ O_k $ is the part of the stabilizer just consisting of rotations of the orthogonal complement. Note that this is all analogous to expressing a Grassmannian as
$$
\text{Gr}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)\cong O_n/(O_{n-k}\times O_k)
$$
One difference is that while taking orthogonal complements gives a canonical isomorphism $ \text{Gr}_{n-k} \cong \text{Gr}_k $ this is not quite true for $ \text{Graff}_{n-k} $ and $ \text{Graff}_{k} $ since they are vector bundles of different dimensions, $ n-k $ versus $ k $, over the same base space $ \text{Gr}_{n-k} \cong \text{Gr}_k $ (the affine Grassmannians only coincide when $ n-k=k $).

At this point it is unclear how all this relates to the title of the question $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 $. To see the connection, first lets consider $ \mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2 $, in other words the Klein bottle. In the same way that the Moebius strip can be viewed as the space of all affine lines in the plane we can sort of "roll up" or "compactify" the Moebius trip by identifying all parallel lines which are an integer distance apart. The action of $ E_2 $ on the set of all collections of parallel lines in the plane that are an integer distance apart is transitive (again $ E_2 $ acts by isometries so take integer distances to integer distances). So the Klein bottle  can be expressed as
$$
 \mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2  \cong E_2/(E_1 \times O_1 \ltimes \mathbb{Z})
$$
where the $ \mathbb{Z} $ factor represents an integer shift from one parallel line to the next. To see this done explicitly in terms of matrices see
[Is it possible to realize the Klein bottle as a linear group orbit?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316503/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-klein-bottle-as-a-linear-group-orbit)
and
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414402/is-it-possible-to-realize-the-moebius-strip-as-a-linear-group-orbit

EDIT: Ok here is the explicit way to do the 2d stuff with matrices:

The Moebius strip is homogeneous for the special Euclidean group of the plane
$$
\operatorname{SE}_2= \left \{ \
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & x \\
-b & a & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : a^2+b^2=1 \right \}.
$$
There is a connected group $ V $ of translations up each vertical line
$$
V= \left \{ \ 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} : y \in \mathbb{R} \right \}.
$$
and
$$
SE_2/V
$$
is a cylinder.
Now if we include the rotation by 180 degrees
$$
\tau:=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $ \langle V, \tau \rangle$ has two connected components and
$$
\operatorname{SE}_2/\langle V, \tau \rangle
$$
is the Moebius strip. The subgroup we are modding out by here is the stabilizer of the $ y $-axis.

Similarly for the compact case, there is an element that shifts horizontally by one unit
$$
b:=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If we mod out $ SE_2 $ by the group generated by $ \langle V,b \rangle \cong \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z} $ we just get a torus. Now if we include the rotation by 180 degrees $ \tau $ then
$$
\operatorname{SE}_2/\langle V,b, \tau \rangle
$$
is a Klein bottle. The subgroup we are modding out by here is the stabilizer of all vertical lines with integer $ x $ intercepts.

Note that we can take either of these constructions and and do it in terms of $ E_2 $, we just have to expand the stabilizer we mod out by to include $ diag(-1,1,1) $ or $ diag(1,-1,1) $ as a generator.

Essentially what we did here is take the vector bundle for the affine Grassmannian and identify it periodically to roll up the fiber into a torus. Indeed one can do this in general to get what I will call $ \text{cGraff} $ the compact affine Grassmanian, a $ k $-torus bundle over $ \text{Gr}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $
$$
T^k \to \text{cGraff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \text{Gr}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n)
$$
This space still has the interesting structure of a transitive action by $ E_n $
$$
\text{cGraff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cong  E_n/(E_{n-k}\times O_k \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^k)
$$
where $ \mathbb{Z}^k $ corresponds to the discrete subgroup of isometries translating by integer amounts along the orthogonal complement. (I feel pretty confident about the codimension 1 case $ \text{cGraff}_{n-k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ but something about $ O_k \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^k $ doesn't seem right as a stabilizer in general for example $ \text{cGraff}_{1}(\mathbb{R}^3) $ the stabilizer of the collection of all lines parallel to z axis with $ x,y$ plane intercept with integer coordinates seems like $ O_2 $ could not stabilize ) So for example
$$
\text{cGraff}_{1}(\mathbb{R}^2) \cong \mathbb{R}P^2 \# \mathbb{R}P^2
$$ is the Klein bottle.

Consider the 3-manifold $ M= \text{cGraff}_{2}(\mathbb{R}^3) $
$$
S^1 \to \text{cGraff}_{2}(\mathbb{R}^3) \to \mathbb{R}P^2
$$
Then $ M $ admits a transitive action by $ E_3 $. This paper

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242949481_Three-dimensional_homogeneous_spaces

seems to strongly imply that the 3-manifold that is a nontrivial circle bundle over $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ and admits a transitive action by $ E_3 $ is in fact $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 $. In other words
$$
\text{cGraff}_{2}(\mathbb{R}^3) \cong \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3
$$
If that really is true, it seems likely that in general the circle bundle over projective space
$$
S^1 \to \text{cGraff}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}
$$
is diffeomorphic to a connected sum
$$
\text{cGraff}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n) \cong \mathbb{R}P^n \# \mathbb{R}P^n
$$
But while I am fairly comfortable with fiber bundles and and smooth homogeneous spaces (manifolds admitting a transitive Lie group action) working with connected sums is a bit out of my wheel house.

**Could someone help me understand why $ \text{cGraff}_{2}(\mathbb{R}^3) \cong \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 $?**

Comment: I am sorry for being slow, by but I don't geometrically understand the $\mathbb{Z}$ action.  I agree that the set of all lines parallel to a given line and integer distance apart has a natural $\mathbb{Z}$ action, but I don't see how to consistently patch these $\mathbb{Z}$ actions together when allowing the given line to vary.

Comment: haha I've been sitting here just relishing the inevitability of someone saying that and now the moment is here! Ya when I came up with the idea this morning and wrote it all done it seemed to make sense but all afternoon I've been on and off thinking about the $ \mathbb{Z}^k $ action and how it interacts with $ O_k $ and the stabilizers and something is definitely fishy. I'll think about it more and write up the case of the Moebius band $ \text{Graff}_1(\mathbb{R}^2) $ which I know works and the Klein bottle $ \text{cGraff}_1(\mathbb{R}^2) $ should work as well. Then I'll get back to you.

Comment: My gut feeling is that if the $\mathbb{Z}$ actions can be made to patch, then the actions will be extendable to $\mathbb{R}$ actions.  This, in turn, would imply that the circle bundles you get are *principal*.  But , e.g. the Klein bottle is not a prinicpal circle bundle over $S^1$.

Comment: I know I know if you look in the edits on my post you'll see that originally I said that $ \text{Graff}_{n−k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ was a principal $ \mathbb{R}^k $ bundle and that  $ \text{cGraff}_{n−k}(\mathbb{R}^n) $ was a principal $ \mathbb{T}^k $ bundle but then I realized both those claims are wrong since Moebius strip and Klein bottle are not principal. Ok @JasonDeVito I added the 2d examples

Comment: I think maybe what it is is that $ SE_2 $ is a principal plane bundle over the circle and the cylinder is just that mod a line and you get a principal line bundle over the circle but then somehow modding out by $ \tau $ ruins everything and its not a principal bundle anymore. Same for torus is just mod out $ SE_2 $ by product of line with the integers and you get the torus which is a principal circle bundle over circle but then you mod out again by $ \tau $ and ruins everything again your bundle is no longer principal.

Comment: Please stop asking such interesting questions ;-).  I have work that I *need* to be doing, and instead find myself thinking about your questions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To begin with, I'm going to set $X = \{\text{oriented $(n-1)$-dimensional planes in }\mathbb{R}^n\}$.

There is a function $f:X\rightarrow S^{n-1}$ defined as follows.  Given a plane $P\in X$, because it is oriented we can define $f(P)$ to be the unique unit normal to $P$ for which $\{P,f(P)\}$ gives the usual orientation on $\mathbb{R}^n$.  It's not too hard to convince yourself that $f$ gives $X$ the structure of an $\mathbb{R}$-bundle over $S^{n-1}$.  Moreover, this bundle is principal: $\mathbb{R}$ acts on $X$ by translating $P$ in the direction of $f(P)$.

By quotient by the restriction of this action to $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we obtain a principal $S^1$-bundle $S^1\rightarrow X/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S^{n-1}$.  I'll write $Y$ for $X/\mathbb{Z}$.

**Proposition 1:** The space $Y$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1\times S^{n-1}$.

*Proof*:  Such a diffeomorphism can just be written down:  Given $P\in X$, the function $\phi:X/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow S^1\times S^{n-1}$ given by $\phi([P]) = (d(P,0)\mod{1}, f(P))$  (where $d(P,0)$ is the *signed* Euclidean distance from the origin $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$) is a diffeomorphism.  $\square$

For later, note that if $-P$ denotes $P$ with the opposite orientation, then $d(-P,0) = - d(P,0)$, and that taken $\mod{1}$, this corresponds to complex conjugation on $S^1\cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.

There is a natural $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ action on $Y$ which maps a class $[P]$ to $[-P]$, where $-P$ refers to $P$ with opposite orientation.
(To save on typing, I'll write $\mathbb{Z}_2$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for the rest of this post.)  This is well defined because all the planes $P\in [P]$ are translates of each other, so have the same orientation.  This action is clearly free, so $Z:= Y/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a manifold.

**Proposition 2**:  The space $Z$ is diffeomorphic to both $\mathbb{R}P^n\sharp \mathbb{R}P^n$ and also to $\operatorname{cGraff}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

The fact that $Z$ is diffeomorphic to $\operatorname{cGraff}_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is almost tautological: a point in $Z$ is an infinite family of parallel planes with integer distance between them.

The fact that $Z$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^n\sharp \mathbb{R}P^n$ will take a bit of work.

For starters, suppose $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts on $S^1\times S^{n-1}$ diagonally via complex conjugation on the $S^1$ factor and the antipodal map on the $S^{n-1}$ factor.  Then it's not too hard to verify that the above diffeomorphism $\phi$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-equivariant.

So, to complete the proof, we only need to show ...

**Proposition 3**:  The space $(S^1\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^n\sharp \mathbb{R}P^n$.

*Proof*:  Observe that there is a decomposition $S^1 = L\cup R$ where $L$ is the left hemisphere and $R$ is the right hemisphere (more rigorously, $L$ consists of the points on $S^1$ with non-positive real part, and $R$ those of non-negative real part.)  Both $L$ and $R$ are preserved by complex conjugation, so it follows that we can view $(S^1\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a union $(L\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cup (R\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$.

From Proposition 4 below, both "halves" are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with a ball removed, so $(S^1\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is obtained by gluing two copies of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with open balls deleted.  That is, $(S^1\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is diffeomorphic to either $\mathbb{R}P^n\sharp \mathbb{R}P^n$ or $\mathbb{R}P^n\sharp -\mathbb{R}P^n$.  However, when $n$ is even, $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is non-orientable, and when $n$ is odd, $\mathbb{R}P^n$ admits an orientation reversing diffeomorphism.  So, up to diffeomorphism, we get $\mathbb{R}P^n\sharp \mathbb{R}P^n$.  $\square$

So, we need only prove Proposition 4.

**Proposition 4**:  Both $(L\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $(R\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^n$ with a ball removed.

*Proof*:  I'll just do the proof for $L$, with the answer for $R$ being similar.

I will identify $L$ with $[-1,1]$ and think of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ as the quotient of $S^n$ by the antipodal action.  Using the usual projective coordinates, we map $L\times S^{n-1}$ to $\mathbb{R}P^n$ via $(t,x)\mapsto [\sin(t), \cos(t)x]$.  Note that $(t,x)$ and $(t',x')$ map to the same point if and only if $(t,x) = \pm (t',x')$.  In particular, this map descends to smooth embedding of $(L\times S^{n-1})/\mathbb{Z}_2$ onto the complement of the ball of radius $1-\sin(1)$ about $[1:0:...:0]$. $\square$

Comment: Wow! What a great answer! You are a hero! Also super weird twist I just stumbled on: it turns out $ \mathbb{R}P^3 \#  \mathbb{R}P^3 $ must be a principal circle bundle since the total space of a circle bundle is orientable if and only if the bundle is principal https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144092/is-every-orientable-circle-bundle-principal and we have bundle $ S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^3 \# \mathbb{R}P^3 \to \mathbb{R}P^2 $

Comment: I'm glad you like it.  However, I don't think this bundle is principal.  The link you posted references the orientation of the bundle, which is a distinct concept from the orientability of the total space.  Orientability of the bundle concerns whether the fiber can be consistently oriented.  When the fiber is connected, the following is true:  Consider orientability of the bundle, base space, and total space.  If any two are orientable, so is the third.  Since $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is non-orientable, but $\mathbb{R}P^3\sharp \mathbb{R}P^3$ is, the bundle itself is not orientable (so not principal.)

Comment: just found this paper "connected sums of compact manifolds and homogeneity" that gives a different proof that the special Euclidean group $ SE_{n} $ acts transitively on $ \mathbb{R}P^n \# \mathbb{R}P^n $ https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=6VqKgvUTncoC&oi=fnd&pg=PA113&ots=wOIe8BSOpm&sig=Te97XY-Ek0y0nq7G4GuOE9vyPTc#v=onepage&q&f=false also I'm very curious about this question on circle bundles over the projective plane https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720917/s1-bundles-over-mathbbrp2 if you want to answer it I'd be very curious to see a classification!

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira:  I had been meaning to work through an answer to that question for some time.  Thanks to your encouragement, I did it.  I just posted it a few minutes ago.

Comment: @JasonDeVito-onhiatus: In the above Proposition 4, can you please explain how to map from $[-1,1] \times  S^{n-1} \rightarrow  RP^n \minus D^n, $ where D^n is disk as you mention above, with radius 1-sin 1 and center [1:0:0...], defined as (t,x) -> [sint , x cost ].